# Relation between DaCapo III and the first two series

Tags: da-capo

I think all DaCapo series might have relation have relation between them . As far as I know from DaCapo I and DaCapo II,

1. In DaCapo II, Shirakawa Nanana is grandchild of Shirakawa Kotori from DaCapo I.
2. Asakuar Junichi is grandfather of both Asakuar Otome and Asakura Yume.

Are there any similar relations in DaCapo III and the previous series?

Comment: There are relations between the characters of all three Da Capo series, but in the case of III this is not supposed to be known to the viewer at the start, and constitutes pretty significant spoilers from the VN (not sure about the anime as I haven't watched it). I can write up an answer about this, but it will be a lot of work so if you'd rather not be spoiled my advice would be to read/watch from the beginning, and everything will be clear by the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only watched the *Da Capo III* anime (which apparently only adapts the prologue of the original visual novel's story), but that features the characters

> Sakura Yoshino and Minatsu Amakase

from *Da Capo II*.